# Selenium and pyautogui does not seem to work together

Tags: python, selenium, scripting, pyautogui

I have script where you write information in pyautogui and it launches a window of selenium. The problem is that when the selenium window is open pyautogui lags to the extent that it is not usable.

I have tried removing all code related to selenium but it seems that just launching the window makes the pyautogui stop working

Here is my current code. Most of the pyautogui stuff was taken from a example at github.

Any help would be appreciated

```
def start_script(information):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.maximize_window()
    # defines the url

    print(information)

    #coordinates = pd.read_excel('Companies.xlsx', header=None)
    #coordinates = str(coordinates.iloc[0, 0])
    coordinates = '67, 67'

    url = 'https://www.google.se/maps/search/AB/@' + coordinates + ',12.5z'
    # opens the website
    driver.get(url)

    fail = True
    while fail == True:
        try:
            driver.find_element(
                By.XPATH, "//div[@class='VtwTSb']//form[1]").click()
        except:
            fail == True
        else:
            fail = False


    while True:
        pass


def make_window(theme):
    sg.theme(theme)
    menu_def = [['&Application', ['E&xit']]]
    
    input_layout = [

        # [sg.Menu(menu_def, key='-MENU-')],
        [sg.Button("Open File")],
        [sg.Text('Search (ab, ltd, etc)')],
        [sg.Input(key='-INPUT-')],
        [sg.Text('Coordinates')],
        [sg.Input(key='-INPUT-')],
        [sg.Spin([i for i in range(1, 11)], initial_value=10,
                 k='-SPIN-'), sg.Text('The level of zoom')],
        [sg.OptionMenu(values=('Right', 'Left', 'Up'),
                       k='-Direction-'), sg.Text('Direction')],
        [sg.Button('Start'), sg.Button('Skip'), sg.Button('Add')]]

    logging_layout = [[sg.Text("Anything printed will display here!")],
                      [sg.Multiline(size=(60, 15), font='Courier 8', expand_x=True, expand_y=True, write_only=True,
                                    reroute_stdout=True, reroute_stderr=True, echo_stdout_stderr=True, autoscroll=True, auto_refresh=True)]
                      # [sg.Output(size=(60,15), font='Courier 8', expand_x=True, expand_y=True)]
                      ]

    layout = [[sg.MenubarCustom(menu_def, key='-MENU-', font='Courier 15', tearoff=True)],
              [sg.Text('Specify the information below and press start', size=(38, 1), justification='center', font=("Helvetica", 16), relief=sg.RELIEF_RIDGE, k='-TEXT HEADING-', enable_events=True)]]
    layout += [[sg.TabGroup([[sg.Tab('Input Elements', input_layout),
                              sg.Tab('Output', logging_layout)]], key='-TAB GROUP-', expand_x=True, expand_y=True),

                ]]
    layout[-1].append(sg.Sizegrip())
    window = sg.Window('Google maps webscraper', layout,
                       grab_anywhere=True, resizable=True, margins=(0, 0), use_custom_titlebar=True, finalize=True, keep_on_top=True)
    window.set_min_size(window.size)
    return window


def main():
    window = make_window(sg.theme())

    # This is an Event Loop
    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
        # keep an animation running so show things are happening
        if event not in (sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT, sg.WIN_CLOSED):
            print('============ Event = ', event, ' ==============')
            print('-------- Values Dictionary (key=value) --------')
            for key in values:
                print(key, ' = ', values[key])
        if event in (None, 'Exit'):
            print("[LOG] Clicked Exit!")
            break
        elif event == "Open File":
            print("[LOG] Clicked Open File!")
            folder_or_file = sg.popup_get_file(  
                'Choose your file', keep_on_top=True)
            sg.popup("You chose: " + str(folder_or_file), keep_on_top=True)
            print("[LOG] User chose file: " + str(folder_or_file))
        elif event == "Start":
            thread_selenium = threading.Thread(target=start_script, args=(values,))
            thread_selenium.start()
        elif event == "Skip":
            print('Skip')
        elif event == "Add":
            print('test')

    window.close()
    exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sg.theme('system default for real')
    sg.theme('DefaultNoMoreNagging')
    main()
```

Comment: I'd recoomend you to rewrite the script only using selenium.

Comment: But selenium does not have any user interface features right? I need my script to be user friendly so i would prefer to have a user interface.